# How to preload information into textbox as page open-angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am beginner anyway. I am trying to preload data back into my textbox as the page opens up. Now, when i hit the button preload, it opens a new page and that is where i want the data to preload of the hero i click on. So if i click hero with index 1, the page opening should preload the details of that hero.

//heroes.html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let hero of Heroes; let i = index" >
    <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-default"  routerLink="../heroes"><em class="fa fa-search"></em></a>Preload</td>
 </tr>
```

//Heroes.detail

```
  export class HeroComponent {

        constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

         Hero = {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
        };
    }
```

//service

```
 getHero(id){
    return this.http.get('http://example.com' +id)
      .map((response:Response) => response.json())
```

Comment: You should read the angular docs about `Resolver` ;)

Comment: This seems to be what you want: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html After that you can check the http-tutorial if necessary ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I suggest you would solve this, is with route parameters, so the following click event passes the hero id to the new page. That means to change your code a bit:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let hero of Heroes; let i = index" >
    <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.lastname}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="goToDetails(hero.id)">View Details</button></td>
 </tr>
```

And in your component:

```
goToDetails(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['detail', id])
}
```

Route needs to be changed too, since you pass the parameter, so your detail route should looks something like this:

```
{
  path: 'detail/:id',
  component: HeroDetailComponent
}
```

And in your DetailComponent you subscribe to the id-parameter and execute the http-request:

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: HeroService)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
    let id = params['id']
    this.service.getHero(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.hero = data;
      });
  })
}
```

More about **[routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)** in the official docs.